Question about cyclic representation C*-algebra
Let $\pi: A \to B(\mathcal{H})$ be a cyclic representation of a $C^*$-algebra $A$, say with cyclic unit vector $\xi_0\in \mathcal{H}$. This means that
$$\overline{\pi(A)\xi_0} = \mathcal{H}$$
where $[-]$ denotes the closed linear span.
Question: Is it also true that $\overline{\pi(A_{\|\cdot\|\le 1})\xi_0}= \mathcal{H}_{\|\cdot\|\le 1}$?

@ThusleGadelankz Thanks for your comment. Corrected. I don't think it is obvious though.

This is still false. For example, let $A = M_2(\mathbb{C})$, $H = L^2(M_2(\mathbb{C}), \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr})$, and $\xi_0 = \hat{1}$. Then $H_{\leq 1}$ consists of matrices with normalized Hilbert-Schmidt norm bounded by $1$ while $\pi(A_{\leq 1})\xi_0$ (or its closure - it is actually already closed in this case) consists of matrices with operator norms bounded by $1$. So, for example, $\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is in the RHS but not in the LHS.

To make the equality true, you need to assume the representation is not just cyclic, but irreducible.

Thanks a lot for the answer!
